# Grails Spring Security UI, user and Role management access

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have installed spring-security-core & spring-security-ui. also added testuser in roleadmin.

when I run the application I get all the controllers list, Login controller worked with username & password. but When click other controller its says

'Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.'

Do I need to add any other role to get the user and role management UI access?

plugin version.

compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"

accessing this URL:
 //127.0.0.1:8080/sec-test/role/search

here is my screen, after login.

[image]

Comment: did you try putting @Secured(['ROLE_USER']) def index = {} before each method in controller

Comment: Yes, this I added in my application contoler it works. how Can I access security plugin user role management contolers?

Comment: as far as i know there is no role management controller

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use Spring security ui. Is there any tutorial how to start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create your roles and test user in BootStrap.groovy:

```
import springsecurity.User
import springsecurity.Role
import springsecurity.UserRole

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
        def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

        def testUser = new User(username: 'testusername', password: '1234')
        testUser.save(flush: true)

        UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

        assert User.count() == 1
        assert Role.count() == 2
        assert UserRole.count() == 1

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Then override as suggested:

```
grails s2ui-override auth
grails s2ui-override layout
grails s2ui-override user package.name
grails s2ui-override role package.name
```

Finally added the secured annotations to your controllers, i.e.:

```
package springsecurity
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class RoleController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RoleController {
}
```

Comment: hi @burt-beckwith , I have upgraded Spring security core,acl and ui to latest version but now if I try to login, I get Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page. Do we need to do anything special as I upgraded from spring security core 1.2,ui 0.2 and acl 1.1.1 versions.

Comment: hi @sfgroups, did above solution solve your problem ? I am getting same error, I tried above solution but could not get success.

Answer (score 5):

better method is make anounymous registration by those instructions :

`grails s2ui-override auth`, `grails s2ui-override layout`, `grails s2ui-override user com.myApp` ,`grails s2ui-override role com.myApp`, `grails s2ui-override register com.myApp`

and add this to Register controller :

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ANONYMOUS'])
class RegisterController extends      grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default grails uses a pessimist approach for url locking, which means that it shows the same message "Sorry you are not authorized to view this URL" if that url is not explicitly white listed. Apart from adding **@Secured** to your controller you could also add the following to your `config/conf.groovy` file and white list the URL:

```
'/action':                    ['ROLE_ADMIN']

'/action' =
```

url to your action. could also be clubbed with wild cards eg:

```
'/**/css/**':                 ['permitAll']

['ROLE_ADMIN'] =
```

the role which can access the url

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, the plugin changed to a pessimistic locking so any thing without a security level defined will throw that 'Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.' message.

Other answers have already said you can just use the s2ui-override script to generate all the controllers and add the @Secure annotation

```
grails s2ui-override user com.myApp
grails s2ui-override role com.myApp
```

then edit to add

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class UserController ...
```

But instead of creating a bunch of empty controllers, you can just modify the static rules file in Config.groovy.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    <snip>
    '/register/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/user/**':                       ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/role/**':                       ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
```

Adding these three lines will make the register controller available to anyone, and the user and role controllers only accessible by ROLE_ADMIN users.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the plugins I need to run this s2ui-override to create the controllers in the application

```
grails s2ui-override auth
grails s2ui-override layout
grails s2ui-override user com.myApp
grails s2ui-override role com.myApp
```

This page was help full.

http://ajibrans.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/spring-security-plugin-with-grails-1-3-7/

Answer (score 0):

user-role mapping is done in UserController.

```
URL - http://127.0.0.1:8080/sec-test/user
```

Comment: I didn't know I have to create user and role contoler for the application. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to create them. Those controllers are provided by the spring security UI plugin.

Comment: Without creating those how can we give access permission to ROLE_ADMIN group?

Answer (score 0):

at config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'/':                              ['permitAll'],
'/**':                              ['permitAll'],
'/index':                         ['permitAll'],
'/user/search':                   ['permitAll'],
'/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/**':   ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
'/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
```

This allows to grant access to all these.. you can also manually configure it.